# Trying to obtain author of answer in nested model gives `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4`

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

today my error is `Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id`.

I've got models & controllers for: User, Ticket, Answers defined in such way:

`User` has many `Answers` & `Tickets`

`Ticket` has many `Answers`

`Answer` belongs to `User` & belongs to `Ticket`

The error appears when in `Ticket` view I'm trying to display `Answers` author (`User`) doing it like this:

`Ticket Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" LIMIT 1
 => #<Ticket id: 8, topic: "This is sample question", message: "This is Sample question with <h1>Some</h1> HTML! <p...", user_id: 1, category_id: 2, created_at: "2013-01-15 12:24:20", updated_at: "2013-01-15 12:24:20", answers_count: 1>`

`Answer Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" LIMIT 1
 => #<Answer id: 6, ticket_id: 8, user_id: 1, message: "This is answer to the sample question with use of h...", created_at: "2013-01-15 12:26:46", updated_at: "2013-01-15 12:26:46">`

`User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, username: "mickula", email: "xx@xx.com", password_hash: "$2a$10$Hty2ekM3t8Dqf0CvZm5zEOwVnXAoytimW9tIOxtfjwNG...", password_salt: "$2a$10$Hty2ekM3t8Dqf0CvZm5zEO", created_at: "2013-01-12 16:55:00", updated_at: "2013-01-12 16:55:00", permission_level: nil>`

```
User.first.answers
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
  Answer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."user_id" = 1
 => [#<Answer id: 6, ticket_id: 8, user_id: 1, message: "This is answer to the sample question with use of h...", created_at: "2013-01-15 12:26:46", updated_at: "2013-01-15 12:26:46">]
```

When I try to display answer `a.user.username` it returns error:

`undefined method username for nil:NilClass`

So it seems like that answer is not connected with user. Could you point me where I did mistake and why it behaves like that? I would like to mention that I did it this way for Tickets and there I can display author of ticket with 
`@ticket.user.username`

Models:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :topic, :message, :user, :category, :category_id
  has_many :answers
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category

end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ticket, :user, :message
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ticket, :counter_cache => true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :answers
end
```

Controller's partials:

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required
  before_filter :admin_required, :only => [:index, :show]
  def index
    @tickets = Ticket.all
  end

  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
  end
end

class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    t_attr = params[:answer].merge :user => current_user
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
    @answer = @ticket.answers.create(t_attr)
    redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
  end
end
```

Edit:
Through console I can obtain answer's author userdata:

```
Ticket.first.answers.first.user
  Ticket Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "tickets".* FROM "tickets" LIMIT 1
  Answer Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."ticket_id" = 8 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, username: "mickula", email: "xx@xx.com", password_hash: "$2a$10$Hty2ekM3t8Dqf0CvZm5zEOwVnXAoytimW9tIOxtfjwNG...", password_salt: "$2a$10$Hty2ekM3t8Dqf0CvZm5zEO", created_at: "2013-01-12 16:55:00", updated_at: "2013-01-12 16:55:00", permission_level: nil>
```

Ticket view:

```
<span class="pull-right">by  <strong><%=h @ticket.user.username %></strong> on  <i><%=h @ticket.created_at %> in <strong><%= @ticket.category.name %></strong></i></span>



<p>
  <strong>Message:</strong><br>
  <%=h @ticket.message %> 
</p>
<h3>Replies</h3>
<%= form_for([@ticket, @ticket.answers.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :message %> <br>
    <%= f.text_area :message, :cols => "50", :rows => "6", :class=> "span12" %><br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<% @ticket.answers.each do |a| %>
    <%= h a.message %> <%= a.user.username %> <%= a.created_at %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Workaround:

```
    <% @ticket.answers.each do |a| %>
    <%= h a.message %> <%= a.user.username if a.user %> <%= a.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

With this condition everything works.
Seems like Loop is doing 1 extra iteration, even if there's no answers.

Comment: Are you sure there is a user with `id = 1`? If not, that would explain why you get nils everywhere.

Comment: 100% sure. Updated the question with result of query from users. I believe if user wouldn't exist I couldn't display it for Ticket

Comment: In that case, there must be something else happening in your view or controller. Can you post the `Ticket` view code, and any partials (if there are any)? That might help.

Comment: Posted controller's partials - nothing special.

Comment: Actually I meant the view & view partials (if there are any).

Comment: Oh sorry, there's only _form partial (from scaffold) and everything is contained in this one view.

Comment: Edited. Seems like loop is doing extra iteration. Still don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails scaffolding creates new, empty object for this:

```
<%= form_for([@ticket, @ticket.answers.build]) do |f| %>
```

to perform form operations like displaying entered form inputs after validation is unsuccesfull (so user won't loose data entered into form fields),
as specified in answers controller:

```
  def create
    t_attr = params[:answer].merge :user => current_user
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:ticket_id])
    @answer = @ticket.answers.create(t_attr)
    redirect_to ticket_path(@ticket)
  end
```

Because of this loop was doing 1 extra iteration (with one object at the end).

To fix it I simply iterate over `ticket.answers.length - 1` objects.